# Add Carbon Format d-M-Y on view blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, format, laravel-5.8

I have data and want to parse at the view.

The Table name is `training` and it is parsing to the view like below:

```
+--+------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+
|id|name        |user_id|no_training|date      |created_at         |updated_at          |
+--+------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+
|1 |software dev|3      |198734-2445|2018-06-20|2019-06-19 19:30:40|2019-06-19 19:30:40 |
+--+------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I want to parse the view so that 'date' is not `2019-06-19`, but instead `19-June-2019` or `19-Juni-2019 (Indonesian(id) Time)`

What do I need to add for my Controller or model?

My Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Training extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'training';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','name','no_training','date',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class ,'user_id');

    }
}
```

my Controller :

```
public function training()
{
    $training = Training::with('users')->get();

    return view('admin.training',['training' => $training]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define some mutators in your Training model.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization):

> #### Customizing The Date Format Per Attribute
>
> You may customize the serialization format of individual Eloquent date
>   attributes by specifying the date format in the cast declaration:
>
> ```
> protected $casts = [
>     'birthday' => 'date:Y-m-d',
>     'joined_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',
> ];
> ```

So in your case..

If you are storing the `date` in a date column (`Date`/`DateTime`) you could do:

**Training.php**

```
protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'date:d-F-Y',
];
```

This should return something like:

> "23-June-2019"

You can check it in [Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker):

```
$ php artisan tinker
> now()->format('d-F-Y');

=> "23-June-2019"
```

Comment: i add 'date' => 'date:d-F-Y', on my model but showing like this . 2018-06-20 00:00:00

Comment: You can also make use of mutators. Please have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Comment: @AdhikMulat could you add the migration of your training table?